# Read current site/site collection term store navigation page URL in the code

Tags: 2013, development, csom, managed-metadata

Dev Environment: SharePoint 2013 On-premise

We have a web part on the home page, where we are **displaying the terms** (reading from Term store navigation). We are doing this by hard coding the term store navigation page URL and Required user name and password to access that term store navigation page.

**Questions are**:

- When we **deploy the WSP in other servers**, it’s not going to work, So is there **any way to read current site/site collection term store navigation page URL?**
- Instead of hard coding the User name and password, how can we run with
  elevated privileges?

To put in simple words, how can we read the below page URL Dynamically in the Code, instead of hard coding. [image]